# Unexpected route chosen while generating an outgoing url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Please, consider the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "route1",
    "{controller}/{month}-{year}/{action}/{user}"
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "route2",
     "{controller}/{month}-{year}/{action}"
);
```

And the following tests:

TEST 1

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    RouteCollection routes = new RouteCollection();
    MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);
    RequestContext context = new RequestContext(CreateHttpContext(), 
                                                new RouteData());

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string result;

    context.RouteData.Values.Add("controller", "Home");
    context.RouteData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
    context.RouteData.Values.Add("user", "user1");
    result = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, "Index", null,
                                    new RouteValueDictionary(
                                        new
                                        {
                                            month = now.Month,
                                            year = now.Year
                                        }),
                                    routes, context, true);
    //OK, result == /Home/10-2012/Index/user1
    Assert.AreEqual(string.Format("/Home/{0}-{1}/Index/user1", now.Month, now.Year), 
                    result);
}
```

TEST 2

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test2()
{
    RouteCollection routes = new RouteCollection();
    MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);
    RequestContext context = new RequestContext(CreateHttpContext(), 
                                                new RouteData());

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string result;

    context.RouteData.Values.Add("controller", "Home");
    context.RouteData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
    context.RouteData.Values.Add("user", "user1");
    context.RouteData.Values.Add("month", now.Month + 1);
    context.RouteData.Values.Add("year", now.Year);
    result = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, "Index", null,
                                    new RouteValueDictionary(
                                        new
                                        {
                                            month = now.Month,
                                            year = now.Year
                                        }),
                                    routes, context, true);
    //Error because result == /Home/10-2012/Index
    Assert.AreEqual(string.Format("/Home/{0}-{1}/Index/user1", now.Month, now.Year), 
    result);
}
```

This test emulates a situation when I already have route values in request context and try to generate an outgoing url with UrlHelper.

The problem is that (presented in test 2), if I have values for all the segments from the expected route (here `route1`) and try to replace some of them through `routeValues` parameter, the wanted route is omitted and the next suitable route is used.

So test 1 works well, as the request context already has values for 3 of 5 segments of route 1, and values for the missing two segments (namely, `year` and `month`) are passed through the `routeValues` parameter.

Test 2 has values for all 5 segments in the request context. And I want to replace some of them (namely, month and year) with other values throught `routeValues`. But route 1 appears to be  *not suitable* and route 2 is used.

Why? What is incorrect with my routes?

Am I expected to clear request context manually in such circumstances?

**EDIT**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test3()
{
    RouteCollection routes = new RouteCollection();
    MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);
    RequestContext context = new RequestContext(CreateHttpContext(), 
                                                new RouteData());

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string result;

    context.RouteData.Values.Add("controller", "Home");
    context.RouteData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
    context.RouteData.Values.Add("month", now.Month.ToString());
    context.RouteData.Values.Add("year", now.Year.ToString());
    result = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, "Index", null,
                                    new RouteValueDictionary(
                                        new
                                        {
                                            month = now.Month + 1,
                                            year = now.Year + 1
                                        }),
                                    routes, context, true);
    Assert.AreEqual(string.Format("/Home/{0}-{1}/Index", now.Month + 1, now.Year + 1), 
                    result);
}
```

This test makes things more confused. Here I'm testing route2. And it works! I have values for all 4 segments in the request context, pass other values through `routeValues`, and the generated outgoing url is OK.

So, the problem is with route1. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

From *Sanderson S. Freeman A. -  Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework Third Edition*:

> The routing system processes the routes in the order that they were
>   added to the RouteCollection object passed to the RegisterRoutes
>   method. Each route is inspected to see if it is a match, which
>   requires three conditions to be met:
>
> 1. A value must be available for every segment variable defined in the URL pattern. To find values for each segment variable, the routing
>      system looks first at the **values we have provided (using the
>      properties of anonymous type), then the variable values for the
>      current request, and finally at the default values defined in the
>      route.**
> 2. None of the values we provided for the segment variables may disagree with the default-only variables defined in the route. *I
>      don't have default values in these routes*
> 3. The values for all of the segment variables must satisfy the route constraints. *I don't have constraints in these routes*

So, according to the first rule I've specified values in an anonymous type, I don't have default values. **The variable values for the current request** - I suppose this to be the values from the request context.

What is wrong with these reasonings for route2, while they work well for route1?

**EDIT**

Actually everything started not from unit tests, but from a real mvc application. There I used [UrlHelper.Action Method (String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460294%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to generate outgoing urls. Since this method is utilized in a layout view (the parent one for the majority of all views), I've taken it into my extension helper method (to exclude extra logic from views), This extension method extracts the action name from the request context, passed to it as an argument. I know I could extract all the current route values through the request context and replace those *year* and *month* (or could I create an anonymous route value collection, containing all the values from the context), but I thought it was superfluous, as mvc automatically took into account the values contained in the request context. So, I extracted only action name, as there were no UrlHelper.Action overload without action name (or I'd have liked even to "not specify" action name too), and added the new month and year through anonymous route value object.

This is an extension method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetPeriodLink(this HtmlHelper html, 
                                          RequestContext context, 
                                          DateTime date)
{
    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(
              urlHelper.Action(
                 (string)context.RouteData.Values["action"], 
                 new { year = date.Year, month = date.Month }));
}
```

As I described in the tests above, it worked for shorter routes (when request context contained only controller, year and month, and action), but failed for a longer one (when request context contained controller, year and month, action, and user).

---

I've posted a workaround I use to make the routing work the way I need.

*While indeed I would love to find out, why on earth do I have to make any workaround in such scenario and what is the key difference between these two routes that prevents `route1` from working the way `route2` does.*

---

**EDIT**

Another remark. As far as the values in request context are of type `string`, I decided to try to set them into the context as strings to ensure there were no type confusion (int vs string). I do not understand, what has changed in this respect, but some of the routes started generating correctly. But not all...This makes yet less sense. I've changed this in a real application, not tests, as the tests have `int` in context, not strings.

Well, I've found the condition under which *route1* is used - it's only used when the values of `month` and `year` in the context are equal to the ones given in the anonymous object. If they differ (in the tests this is true both for `int` and `string`), *route2* is used. But why?

This confirms what I have in my real application:

1. I had `string`s in the context, but provided `int`s through the anonymous object, it somehow confused the mvc and it couldn't use `route1`.
2. I changed `int`s in the anonymous object to `string`s, and the urls where `month` and `year` in context are equal to the ones in the anonymous object, started generating correctly; whereas all others didn't.

So, I see one rule: the properties of the anonymous object should be of type `string` to match the type of the route values in the request context.

But this rule seems to be **not compulsory**, as in *Test3*, I changed the types (you may see it now above) and it still works correctly. MVC manages to cast types itself correctly.

---

Finally I found the explanation to all this behaviour. Please, see my answer below.

Comment: Without knowing 'for certain', I believe when you generate your route with the URLHelper.GenerateUrl, the route value dictionary that you are passing is overwriting everything that was already in the route value dictionary.  Try adding the user parameter in the GenerateUrl call and see if this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quick workaround I use to get it work:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetPeriodLink(this HtmlHelper html, 
                                          RequestContext context, 
                                          DateTime date)
{
    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context);

    context.RouteData.Values["month"] = date.Month;
    context.RouteData.Values["year"] = date.Year;

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(
              urlHelper.Action(
                 (string)context.RouteData.Values["action"]));
}
```

<s>I simply remove the `month` and `year` entries from the `context.RouteData.Values`.</s> I simply replace the `month` and `year` entries on the request context. If delete them from context (as I did at first), they would be unavailable for the helpers' methods invoked after this one.

This approach makes my extension method work by the scenario, described in *Test 1* (please, see the question).

---

**FINALY**

Carefully rereading **Sanderson S., Freeman A. -  Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework (3rd edition)** I at least found the explanation of all this stuff:

*Part 2 ASP.NET MVC in detail*

*Chapter 11 URLs, Routing and Areas*

*Generating outgoing URLs*

in section **Understanding segment variable reuse**:

> The routing system will reuse values only for segment variables that
>   occur earlier in the URL pattern than any parameters that are supplied
>   to the Html.ActionLink method.

As far as my `month-year` segment is met right after `controller` and I do specify values for `month` and `year`, all trailing segments (`action`,`user`) are not reused. As far as I do nor specify them in my anonymous object, they appear to be unavailable for the route. So, route1 cannot match.

In the book there is even a warning:

> The best way to deal with this behavior is to prevent it from
>   happening. We strongly recommend that you do not rely on this
>   behavior, and that you supply values for all of the segment variables
>   in a URL pattern. Relying on this behavior will not only make your
>   code harder to read, but you end up making assumptions about the order
>   in which your users make requests, which is something that will
>   ultimately bite you as your application enters maintenance.

Well, it has bitten me)))

Worth to lose 100 rep to remember (I shall even repeat it here again) the rule: **The routing system will reuse values only for segment variables that occur earlier in the URL pattern than any parameters that are supplied.**

Answer (score -1):

Would one route with a default for user be enough?  That is

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "route1",
    "{controller}/{month}-{year}/{action}/{user}",
    new { user = "" }
);
```

Otherwise you would have to allow something more specific to the user route so it would not match route2 first when creating the url.

Update: I'd suggest leaving your helper and work directly with Url.Action, here are two tests for your scenario above:

```
 [TestFixture]
    public class RouteRegistrarBespokeTests
    {
        private UrlHelper _urlHelper;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            var routes = new RouteCollection();
            routes.Clear();
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            RegisterRoutesTo(routes);
            var requestContext = new RequestContext(HttpMocks.HttpContext(), 
                                           routeData);
            _urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext, routes);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Should_be_able_to_map_sample_without_user()
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var result = _urlHelper.Action("Index", "Sample", 
                               new {  year = now.Year, month = now.Month });
            Assert.AreEqual(string.Format("/Sample/{0}-{1}/Index", 
                                      now.Month, now.Year ), result);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Should_be_able_to_map_sample_with_user()
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var result = _urlHelper.Action("Index", "Sample", 
                          new { user = "user1", year = now.Year, 
                                month = now.Month });
            Assert.AreEqual(string.Format("/Sample/{0}-{1}/Index/{2}", 
                                     now.Month, now.Year, "user1"), result);
        }



private static void RegisterRoutesTo(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute("route1", "{controller}/{month}-{year}/{action}/{user}");
    routes.MapRoute("route2", "{controller}/{month}-{year}/{action}");
}

}
```

Comment: How does your answer explain all the behaviour described in my "very short" answer and "nor more short-spoken" bounty message?

Comment: i'll take a fuller read later, seemed very complicated for a simple task but not get you're trying to understand things more fully.

Comment: Nevertheless I've checked your suggestion and replaced both my routes with your one. The result appeared to be 100% the same as I described in my question's last edit. Nothing has changed. So, it neither solves the problem (I hope, I've explained why in my own answer posted above), nor explains it.

Comment: I tryed to develop your idea and added a default value for `action`: `new { user = "", action = "Index" }` - for this route to have default values for both segments to the right from the `{month}-{year}`...but the result still appeared not what I wanted - it replaced the segment value for `user` (that was available in the request context) with the default value (i.e. empty string)..it's all suits well the explanations provided in the book after Sanderson S., Freeman A.

Comment: I guess **no such speculation will work**. And the only thing I should do is **change my approach and do provide all the necessary values through the anonymous object**.

Comment: this helper does seem to be making things a little more complicated than clearer.  why not work with the Url.Action directly in your code rather than abstracting behind this helper?  I've added some simple tests to answer on how the routes should map easily with url action (i mock the request differently)

Comment: How am I expected to check your tests? Firstly, I have no idea what `HttpMocks` is. Secondly, as you could see in my question, I manually filled request context with segment variables to emulate the situation in which I wanted these routes to work in a real application (I can say, I managed to do that, as in a large number of variations my tests coincide with the real application). You don't even try to do that. So, how do you want your tests to help me solve the issue?

Comment: I've used the extension method to extract code, working with the request context from view. I'm trying to follow the pattern to leave as liitle logic in views as possible. the extension method did not confuse me even a bit. Besides the extension method does work directly with `UrlHelper.Action`.